# How to solve blank page after posting the form problem?

Tags: python, django

I want to send a basic form to views. I create everything that it need but when I submit the post, it doesn't send a return a blank page.
This is my form and app:reports is the same page with form, because I want to return the same page. I need the values of year_one and year_two.

```
<form  method="post" action="{% url 'app:reports' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="year_one">Select year 1:</label>
    <select id="year_one" name="year_one">
        {% for case in query_trend %}
            <option value="{{case.date_created__year}}"  >{{case.date_created__year}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <label for="year_two">Select year 2:</label>
    <select id="year_two" name="year_two">
        {% for case in query_trend %}
            <option value="{{case.date_created__year}}">{{case.date_created__year}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <button onclick="test()">click</button>
</form>
```

And this is my view

```
if self.request.method == 'POST':
            year_one = self.request.GET.get('year_one')
            year_two = self.request.GET.get('year_two')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('fdm:outstanding_reports')
```

What should I do for using these values in views?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your button's test() method is successfully submitting the form...If you are passing the request to your view,ie,

```
def reports(request):
```

Then you can refer to the posted values of year_one and year_two as:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        year_one = request.POST.get('year_one')
        year_two = request.POST.get('year_two')
```

(GET is when you send values contained in the URL, eg page?year_1=1975&year_2=1300, POST is when it happens in the background. A form will generally use only one or the other, so you your version probably wasn't getting any values. Confusingly, you also use the lowercase '.get()' to retrieve the POST values)